# Can't install older version of .NET

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

## The problem:

I have a project in Unity, and am coding in Visual Studio Code. In order to use the VSCode "C#" extension, **I need .NETFramework version 4.7.1**. Here's the error message the extension throws if I don't have it:

```
Failed to load project file 'c:\Desenvolvimento\Projetos\Emergent-RPG-Prototype\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
c:\Desenvolvimento\Projetos\Emergent-RPG-Prototype\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
c:\Users\Gui Mendel\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17\.omnisharp\1.38.1-beta.15\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Problem is, I accidentally installed version 4.8, which doesn't satisfy the extension. The same installer for version 4.8 allows me to uninstall it, which I did, but for some reason, when I now try to install version 4.7.1, I get the following error:

```
.NET Framework 4.7.1 or a later update is already installed on this computer.
```

It says I can find more information about blocked installations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations), but this page annoyingly states *no action necessary* in my case scenario (which isn't the case as this problem keeps me from installing the version I need).

## What I've tried:

I tried [this page's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows) advice on uninstalling the sdk for good, but it doesn't show up as installed in any of the provided methods. I think it really is uninstalled, but somehow the 4.7.1 installer believes otherwise.

In [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) though, I found out there seems to be a registry key which holds what sdk version is installed. And in fact, there I found it, a key stating I have version 4.8 installed. I completely removed the NET Framework subkey, rebooted, but the problem *still persisted*. I haven't restored it, but in case I need to, I do have it backed up.

## Question:

**What do I have to do to be able to install version 4.7.1?**

**Please** let me know if any necessary information is missing, I've posted all I could think of.

## Additional Info

- The 4.8 installer still works, I can reinstall this version if I want
  to.
- The extension error suggests retargeting the application, but
  this isn't possible with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, turns out I solved my own problem while researching for this question. Posting it here in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

## The Solution

Head to the [4.7.1 version download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net471) (or a later version if you need to). You might be tempted to download it with the Developer Pack button on the right, but **don't** - you'd run into the same problem:

[image: screen shot of wrong download link]

> Don't download this one

Instead, head down to *Advanced downloads* and **pick the "Offline Installer" Developer Pack**:

[image]

> Download this one instead

It's a rather simple solution, but it could render you sleepless if you didn't look for it in the right place.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Was gonna say. You need the developer pack not actually dot net